# Нужно ли поставить здесь тире?

Tags: тире

Сон - имба. Ставить ли тире? Или нет?

Comment: Хотелось бы разъяснение по тексту, что имеется ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

Слово *имба* в последнее время часто используется для положительно оценки чего-либо.

Часто на Алиэкспресс натыкаюсь на русскозычные отзывы типа "Куртка — имба", "Кеды — имба", "Пальто просто имба". Туда же производное прилагательное *имбовый* в сочетаниях типа "Имбовые кроссовки".

Т. е. существительное имба в данных предложениях явно испольуется в значении "хорошая штука", "офигенная штука", "что-то потрясающее".

Выходит, "Сон — имба" — это двусоставное предложение с подлежащим-существительным и сказуемым-существительным. Связки между ними нет. Допустимо ставить тире в предложениях такого состава.

Я бы поставил тире, однако это простое разговорное предложение, и поэтому, если хочется, можно обойтись и без тире.

Comment: то есть, ты даже не в курсе, что такое имба?